# NLog WebService target creates too much connections

Tags: .net, nlog

I have a .NET Core 3.1 service which make use of NLog.
Here is my NLog.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog autoReload="true"
      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="AsyncInformation" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
      <target type="WebService"
                  name="ws"
                  url="https://log-api.com/log/v1"
                  protocol="JsonPost">
        <parameter name="">
          <layout xsi:type="newrelic-jsonlayout">
            <attribute name="time" layout="${date}" />
            <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
            <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
            <attribute name="host" layout="${machinename}" />
            <attribute name="ActivityId" layout="${activityId}" />
            <attribute name="processId" layout="${processId}" />
            <attribute name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
            <attribute name="event-properties" >
              <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" maxRecursionLimit="0" escapeForwardSlash="true" />
            </attribute>
            <attribute name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
            <attribute name="traceId" layout="${var:traceId}" />
          </layout>
        </parameter>
        <header name="X-License-Key" layout="${environment:LICENSE_KEY}"/>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Information" maxlevel="Error" writeTo="AsyncInformation"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

My service is hosted in Azure and I can see that code is running and I can see also the logs arrive into in my API.
Service performance been hit and the CPU usage is very high (most of the time 100%), **I have noticed that our open connections have been increased from 700 to 2,000** (which is the maximum amount of allowed connections) which I believe is the source of the performance issue.

I tried to get into NLog source code and noticed that WebService target (which I use) is using HttpWebRequest which I believe is the reason for these huge amount of connections that being opened because the connection is not persistence. I wonder if there is an option use the WebService target but with reusing the connections by keeping the connections alive?

Or there is an option to use HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest in the WebService target?

Any help would be great.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` was not completely ready with NetCore3.1

- Microsoft initially decided that `HttpWebRequest` was completely crap and should NOT be part of the NetCore-platform.
- Microsoft then acknowledged that adding `HttpWebRequest` to NetCore woul would make the transition easier from NetFramework. Microsoft also decided that `HttpWebRequest` should just be a slim wrapper for `HttpClient`, where each `HttpWebRequest` creates their own `HttpClient`-instance, thus killing Http-Connection-pooling (Ignoring [KeepAlive = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive))
- Microsoft later acknowledged that making an implementation of `HttpWebRequest`, that fails to meet the actual documentation and expected behavior would give a bad reputation. With the release of Net50 then Microsoft closed many of the issues with its initially half-baked `HttpWebRequest`.

See also: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/41462

I can see 2 directions:

- Update to Net50 (from NetCore31) and add `proxyType="DefaultWebProxy"` as option for `WebService`-target.
- Try the [NLog.Targets.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Http) and see if it can support your scenario.

Comment: My solution should support various services that most of them are .NET Core based. So the first option is not relevant for me, but for the second suggestion you mentioned - to use http target, I would be glad to use that but so far I couldn’t find a way to add a header to my request, the reason I chose WebService target was because I was able to add my header to the request (see in the code above). Am I missing something and there is actually a way to add headers into http target request?

Comment: @user2055886 I guess you could start with creating an issue for the https://github.com/DarekDan/NLog.Targets.HTTP , and if you are really excited then also create a pull-request that resolves the issue.